# How to update (nodejs14.x) while having node version v16.14.2?

Tags: node.js, turbo

I am beginner in node trying to create rest-api's using node and express. Following the udemy course https://www.udemy.com/course/create-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-mongo-db/.

In this turbo server is used and site is deployed on that. Now I want to deploy my project on turbo server but getting following error

```
    lenovo@siddhi:~/giftshop-api$ turbo deploy


Deploying to Turbo 360 Hosting Environment...

...............

ERROR: The runtime parameter of nodejs10.x is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs14.x) while creating or updating functions.
```

I have installed the node already with version

```
lenovo@siddhi:~/giftshop-api$ node -v
v16.14.2
```

How can I use runtime of (nodejs14.x) while creating or updating functions.?

Tried many solutions of from stack overflow but couldn't get it done.

Can anyone help please...

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this `turbo`, but maybe you have some configuration specifying a node version to be `10.x` because it's an outdated tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

You can install nvm by following the instructions at https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
Finally, everything is just

```bash
nvm install <node-version>
nvm use <node-version>
```

You need to run it as admin at cmd